# Content type adding page is not displaying properly

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a content type and added fields to that . But when try to add a content (the page url is **`base_url/node/add/content_type`**) it appear as an **administral adding option** (Means its not showing the **`main navigation`** and **`side navigation`** and **`header images`**) . Why is it like that ? One thing i noticed that its breadcrumb appear as **`Home >> Add content`**, but in real it should be ( that appear in my staging server as **`Home >> Node >> Add content`** and **`appearing the side navigation and main navigation menus`** )  . I installed **`node`** **`module`** too .  How could achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For admin users you can change this at the bottom of theme settings:

**/admin/appearance**

☑  Use the administration theme when editing or creating content

On the staging server you probably testing this with a non admin user account, so you won't see a difference there.